# Cmake option default value

Tags: cmake

If I have a CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

OPTION(FOO "Foo Option" OFF)

MESSAGE("FOO? " ${FOO})
```

And then I call cmake on it, I get the following output:

```
FOO? ON
```

Why is this? Haven't I specified the default for FOO is to be OFF?

Comment: clear your build directory

Answer (score 7):

Delete CMakeCache.txt from build directory and reload project. This happens because CMake is caching global variables

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SET(FOO OFF CACHE BOOL "Foo Option")
```

or

```
SET(FOO OFF CACHE BOOL "Foo Option" FORCE)
```

Answer (score 4):

You may open up cmake gui.It can show you every each option value. The option value in build folder may different with default value.

Recheck your CMakeLists.txt file. Maybe somewhere you set value on it.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
OPTION(FOO "Foo Option" OFF)
SET(FOO ON)                   # Don't do this
MESSAGE("FOO? " ${FOO})
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting our entire build directory as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/56119191/895245 you could also try to unset just one variable with:

```
cmake -U FOO
```

to ensure that it is not being cached to a non-default value.