# CMake option default value is ignored

Tags: cmake

Given the following CMake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(foo)
option(XXX "List of things" "a;b;c")
message(STATUS "XXX is ${XXX}")
```

`cmake ..` *with a completely clean build directory* prints

```
-- XXX is OFF
```

Why doesn't the default value work? Note that this question is specifically about it not working *when the build directory is clean* so [this question is not a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015940/cmake-option-default-value).

Answer (score 2):

Ah `option()` is only intended to be used for booleans. The default value can only be `TRUE` or `FALSE` (or their many aliases).

For non-boolean options you need to do:

```
set(var_name "Default value" CACHE STRING "Help text")
```